# Desktop webpage

Tags: html, internet-explorer, windows-xp

I have a webpage which has links to documents (MS Word .doc files).  If you view this webpage on IE8 directly, and click on one of these document links, it opens up a new IE8 window/tab and displays the document directly in IE8 with a limited MS Word tool bar which is perfect.

If I then change the desktop background to the webpage, if the user then clicks on the same document links above, the documents open directly is MS Word.  Why is this happening?  I need it to continue to open directly in a new IE8 window.

This is what the HTML link looks like:

`<a href="file:///C:/folder/document1.doc" target="_blank">Document 1</a>`

This bit of HTML works perfectly in IE8 directly, but when the web page which contains this link is used via `right click desktop in XP > Properties > Desktop > Customize Desktop > Web` where the webpage url is added to show the webpage on the desktop, if I then click on the above document1.doc link, it opens in MS Word instead of IE8.

Comment: `If I then change the desktop background to the webpage`. I don't get it?

Comment: @rsplak I think he means [Active Desktop](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Active_Desktop).

Comment: @FredrikO, Added to question above.

Comment: @rsplak, If you right click your XP desktop followed by, Properties > Desktop > Customize Desktop > Web, here you can convert your desktop background wallpaper into a working webpage by specifying a URL.

Comment: @oshirowanen, FrederikO. Never knew that. Can't test it, ubuntu here

Comment: @oshirowanen: I hope you're aware that what you're building might not work in new Window versions. "Windows Vista has replaced the Active Desktop with Windows Sidebar", "It appears that the 64-bit version of Windows XP no longer supports Active Desktop.", etc. (from Wikipedia)

Comment: Of course it will open in word. The default file type association with .doc is MS Word if installed. You might try changing that open with default. Of course it should be noted that **all** doc files will then open in IE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default behaviour when opening MS Word files in IE8 is to open them in a new tab with the limited toolbar. When you are using the same page as a background on Active Desktop you are no longer using IE8, and therefore it will open directly in MS Word.

So, I dont think there is a way to "embed" the document as a background or to trigger it to open IE8.

Answer (score 3):

You could indeed try to set the target to `_blank`, but if this doesn't work, I think i have a solution.

Create a new html page in the same directory as the one you're running from your desktop.

This should be the content:

//keep in mind: the javascript code ain't mine, but it works ;).

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function getQuerystring(key, default_)
{
  if (default_==null) default_=""; 
  key = key.replace(/[\[]/,"\\\[").replace(/[\]]/,"\\\]");
  var regex = new RegExp("[\\?&]"+key+"=([^&#]*)");
  var qs = regex.exec(window.location.href);
  if(qs == null)
    return default_;
  else
    return qs[1];
}
document.location = getQuerystring('redirect');
</script>
</head>
<body>
you're being redirected
</body>
</html>
```

On it's own, this file doesn't do anything. But if you change the links on your desktop HTML file to

`NAME_OF_NEW_FILE_THAT_YOU_JUST_MADE.html?redirect=LINK_THAT_YOU_HAD_BEFORE`

it's all a little sketchy, but it works. It will open in your browser, because it's HTML. And it will open your file as well, thanks to JS

Answer (score 0):

target = "_blank" would open in a new tab, which I don't think Active Desktop supports. Try target = "_self"